# Looking for a quote about painting

Tags: quotes

I dimly remember a quote from high school art class that went something like "*You must learn to paint the sky blue before you can paint it red.*" I thought it was from Picasso, but my searches are coming up empty. All of my Google searches are also coming up empty. Does anyone know anything about this quote, or know where I should be looking? I've also tried some of the common quote collection sites with no results. It's a very specific quote that I feel also has meaning in other areas of life.

My apologies if this is not an appropriate forum for the question.

Comment: After some more searching I found this: `Artists can colour the sky red because they know it's blue. Those of us who aren't artists must colour things the way they really are or people might think we're stupid. (Jules Feiffer)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm remembering the quote wrong, or if this is just a similar quote. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Picasso said "*Combien de fois, au moment de mettre du bleu, j’ai constaté que j’en manquais. Alors,  j’ai  pris  du  rouge  et  je  l’ai  mis  à  la  place  du  bleu.  Vanité  des  choses  de l’esprit*." (how many times, when I wanted touse blue, I realized that it was missing. Then I took red instead. Vanity of things!)

Answer (score 3):

Jules Feiffer, the satirist, was obviously giving a backhanded compliment to the artistic fraternity when he wrote "Artists can colour the sky red because they know it's blue. Those of us who aren't artists must colour things the way they really are or people might think we are stupid".
A view of the art world many would share.